# SQL GROUP BY find max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Item,Pricelist1,HisDate` and another table have `Pricelist2`.

In the following query I am using to find `pricelist1` and `pricelist2` with less than user input date

```sql
(Select
    MAX(ZA.CDU_HisDate) 'HISDATE',
    ZA.CDU_Item,
    ZA.CDU_CPrice1,
    ZB.CDU_Price2
 from TDU_PriceHistory ZA
 INNER Join TDU_PriceListDetails ZB on 
     ZA.CDU_CArtigo=ZB.CDU_Item and ZA.CDU_PL=ZB.CDU_PriceList
 where ZA.CDU_HisDate <= @todate
     and ZA.CDU_PL ='PL03'
 group by 
     ZA.CDU_cartigo,
     ZA.CDU_CPrice1,
     ZB.CDU_Price2
)
```

If I use `GROUP by` only by `cartigo`, its perfect. If I use `GROUP BY Item,Price1,Price2` then its all available dates and price detail.

I want to find only Maximum date and relevant Price list

Comment: Whitespace doesn't cost, neither does spell-checking. Please [edit] and add sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly to your question, the answer may be in this way.

```
WITH 
    MaxDateForItem AS ( --  The max hisdate of item for user input date
        SELECT ZA.CDU_Item, MAX(ZA.CDU_HisDate) Max_CDU_HisDate 
        FROM TDU_PriceHistory ZA 
        WHERE ZA.CDU_HisDate <= @todate
            AND ZA.CDU_PL = 'PL03'
    ),
    ItemPriceAtMaxDate AS (
        SELECT T1.CDU_Item, T1.CDU_CPrice1, T1.CDU_HisDate, T1.CDU_CArtigo, T1.CDU_PL
        FROM TDU_PriceHistory T1
        INNER JOIN MaxDateForItem T2 ON T1.CDU_Item = T2.CDU_Item AND T1.CDU_HisDate = T2.Max_CDU_HisDate
        WHERE T1.CDU_PL = 'PL03'
    )
SELECT TMP1.CDU_HisDate AS HISDATE, TMP1.CDU_Item, TMP1.CDU_Price1, ZB.CDU_Price2
FROM ItemPriceAtMaxDate TMP1
INNER JOIN TDU_PriceListDetails ZB ON TMP1.CDU_CArtigo = ZB.CDU_Item
    AND TMP1.CDU_PL = ZB.CDU_PriceList;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help dbcabadab055, but my problem again grouping ,because i have many PL's are in the list , if i not grouping cdu_pl on  MaxDateForItem then I cannnt match with ItemPriceAtMaxDate